# ¿Cómo crear los métodos onRestart, onResume, onPause, etc en un adaptador?

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview

Estoy tratando de crear el método `onRestart` en mi clase adaptador de un `RecyclerView` para que cada vez que yo regrese a la clase los productos que agregue anteriormente se eliminen desde el método `onRestart`, sin embargo, al escribir el siguiente código:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    for(int i=0; i<recyclerAdapter.getSize(); i++) {
        recyclerAdapter.delete(i);
    }
    PostCall doPostCall = new PostCall();  
 doPostCall.execute();
}
```

Me lanza los siguientes errores

> El override : "Method does not override method from its superclass"

> El onRestart : "Cannot resolve method 'onRestart' in 'Adapter'"

¿Alguien sabe cuál es la manera correcta de utilizar estos métodos dentro de un adaptador?

Comment: Debes buscar otra solución, Los métodos que deseas usar son exclusivos de la Actividad
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=es como almacenas los productos?

Comment: Como indica @Jorgesys y el error que arroja tu máquina, el metodo onRestart es de la clase Activity, si tienes una referencia en tu Activity del Adapter, puedes crear una función en el adapter que borre los datos, y llamarla desde la funcion onRestart del activty.

Comment: Gracias por aclarar mi dudad.